# What is an optimal way to get parent node for every current node in many-hop Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of files and folders and I essentially want a query - given a `folderId` - that brings back the entire sub-directory structure recursively, including each node's `parentId`.

I came up with this solution (note: Cypher 2.0):

```
match p = (f:folder)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->c 
where f._id = 3 
return case when c._id = f._id then null 
          else nodes(p)[length(p)-1]._id end as parentId, c;
```

That seems to work. However I feel like there must be a cleaner way. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to explicitly identify the parent node on the path,

```
Match f:Folder-[:CONTAINS*0..]->parent-[:CONTAINS]->c
where f._id = 3
Return parent._id as parent, c._id as current
```

The result would not include the row for the given starting folder f. but since it is a fixed value, if you really need to include that in the query result, you can always append it to the result as follows,

```
Match f:Folder-[:CONTAINS*0..]->parent-[:CONTAINS]->c
where f._id = 3
Return parent._id as parent, c._id as current
Union
Return null as parent, 3 as current
```

Comment: That works... I had to wrap `f:folder` in parenthesis though.